# MySQL 5.6 Show ALL Grants for User

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I have a MySQL pair that communicates over a VIP. I want to verify permissions for all users (including root) from ANY IP. When I attempt to view all grants for root I get this:

```
mysql> show grants for root;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host '%'
```

But there are other grants for root:

```
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `*.*`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'                                                                                  |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**How can I view ALL grants for a user (all hosts and databases)?**

Comment: I think you would get help from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497317/how-can-i-view-all-grants-for-an-sql-database)

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/mysql-show-grants-for-all-users

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES;
```